# How to return all rows in a group where a specific value appears at least once

Tags: sql-server

How can I return all rows in group of records where a specific value appears?

For instance here is the example table:

```
id code
1  E100
1  E200
1  E300
2  E100
2  E300
3  E300
3  E400
```

In this table I want to get all `id`'s and `code`'s, where the code `E100` appears. So if it appears against `id=1`, I want to return all rows where `id=1`.

Desired output based on above data:

```
id code
1  E100
1  E200
1  E300
2  E100
2  E300
```

`id=3` is not included as it doesn't hold a value `E100` in the `code` column.

Comment: this questions in not clear

Answer (score 1):

Use `Exists Operator`

```
select * 
from yourtable a
where exists 
(
select 1 
from yourtable b 
where a.id=b.id 
and b.code ='E100'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id IN (
   SELECT id FROM Table WHERE code = 'E100'
)
```

Comment: Why you need Distinct in sub-query

Comment: It's not needed for the result to be correct but I like to get as few results as possible from sub-queries. I imagine it's best practice and increases response times(?)

Comment: Its a additional overhead for the sql server to remove the duplicates, which is not required here

Comment: I just assumed it worked another way but you are of course correct (I found a thread about Distinct).